# Pass row id into a loop C#

Tags: c#, html

I have a table where each td has an id of the form "A0XJ" where values of the x and j represent the row and column number. I want to programmatically update the values of the table data inner text (values which I will get from a datatable.

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
  <td id="A011"></td>
  <td id="A012"/><td>
  <td id="A013"></td>
  <td id="A014"></td>
  <td id="A015"></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="A021"></td>
  <td id="A022"></td>
  <td id="A023"></td>
  <td id="A024"></td>
  <td id="A025"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

In the c# code i have build a loop in order to have automatic filling of all data. The problem I have is that I am not sure about the datatype I should use for this. I am using string (which is definitely not the right type)
 I am getting the following error 'string does not contain a definition for InnerText and no extension method innertext :

```
     protected void FILL_DATA(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable IACS = new DataTable();
        IACS= GenerateTransposedTableinCsharp(generateIacs());

        for (int i = 6; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            String  rowtext ="A0" + i;
            for (int j = 1; j <= 14; j++)
            {
                String text = rowtext + j;
                text.InnerText= IACS.Rows[i-5].Field<string>(j);
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you maybe please rephrase the specified input and the expected outcome. Somehow it is not really clear "what you have" and where you want to go

Comment: In which form do you have the HTML? Is that what `IACS` holds? If so, in which form? What is in each cell of the data table? Just the ID, the whole HTML markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat the table element like a control that can be updated from your c# code, you need to add the `runat="server"` attribute and give the table an ID:

```
<table border="1" id="tableIACS" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td id="A011"></td>
        <td id="A012"></td>
        <td id="A013"></td>
        <td id="A014"></td>
        <td id="A015"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="A021"></td>
        <td id="A022"></td>
        <td id="A023"></td>
        <td id="A024"></td>
        <td id="A025"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can reference the cells within it by ID using `FindControl()`

```
protected void FILL_DATA(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable IACS = new DataTable();
    IACS = GenerateTransposedTableinCsharp(generateIacs());

    for (int i = 6; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        String rowtext = "A0" + i;
        for (int j = 1; j <= 14; j++)
        {
            String text = rowtext + j;
            HtmlTableCell cell = tableIACS.FindControl(text) as HtmlTableCell;
            if (cell != null)
                cell.InnerText = IACS.Rows[i - 5].Field<string>(j);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are having trouble getting a properly formatted `text` string in the form "A0XJ" where X is the row and J is the column.

Then your problem is that you aren't building your string correctly. `text` is not being updated correctly through each iteration in your inner loop or outer loop.

Below is my solution

```
protected void FILL_DATA (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable IACS = new DataTable ();
    IACS = GenerateTransposedTableinCsharp (generateIacs ());
    for (int i = 6; i <= 8; i++) {

        string rowText = "A0" + i; // this gets updated for each outer iteration

        for (int j = 1; j <= 14; j++) {
            string text = rowText + j; // text is now in the form A0XJ
            // convert string to object id
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem persists. The error that I get is that "string does not contain a definition for inner text".'Text' is recognized as String not as an td id (object).

Comment: @el94 That's because "InnerText" is not a property of the "String" class (I should have seen that mistake before). I fixed the code.

Comment: That is my biggest problem, I want to convert the string to the object id which is a table data and the td has an id and InnerText is a valid property of td.

Comment: I want to achieve that the inner text of td A0XJ = to values of IACS.Rows [i - 5].Field<string> (j) which is a value in another datatable.

Comment: I can't help you with that. You didn't give enough information for me to know how to do that (like what library you're using).

Comment: Hey, I just edited the question, would you mind having a look at it?